# Why is my html body overlapping my footer?

Tags: html, css

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but I'm trying to apply styles within my message.html and my code is overlapping with my footer. How do I make this not overlap? Still new to html/css and have been dealing with this problem in other parts of my code. How do I make my css changes only apply to this specific code?

**message.html**

```
{% extends "dating_app/base.html" %}

<title>Profile</title>

<!DOCTYPE html>



{% block styles %}
    body{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background: #f1f1f1;
        font-family: arial;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
        .card-container{
        width: 300px;
        height: 430px;
        background: #FFF;
        border-radius: 6px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 1px #000;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: inline-block;
    }
        .upper-container{
        height: 150px;
        background: #7F00FF;
    }
        .image-container{
        background: white;
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        padding: 5px;
        transform: translate(100px,100px);
    }
        .image-container img{
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
        .lower-container{
        height: 280px;
        background: #FFF;
        padding: 20px;
        padding-top: 40px;
        text-align: center;
    }
        .lower-container h3, h4{
        box-sizing: border-box;
        line-height: .6;
        font-weight: lighter;
    }
        .lower-container h4{
        color: #7F00FF;
        opacity: .6;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
        .lower-container p{
        font-size: 16px;
        color: gray;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
        .lower-container .btn{
        padding: 12px 20px;
        background: #7F00FF;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        border-radius: 30px;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        transition: all .3s ease-in;
    }
    .lower-container .btn:hover{
        background: transparent;
        color: #7F00FF;
        border: 2px solid #7F00FF;
    }

{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Profile Card</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="card-container">
         <div class="upper-container">
            <div class="image-container">
               <img src="profile.jpg" />
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="lower-container">
            <div>
               <h3>Alaina Wick</h3>
               <h4>Front-end Developer</h4>
            </div>
            <div>
               <p>sodales accumsan ligula. Aenean sed diam tristique,
                  fermentum mi nec, ornare arch.
               </p>
            </div>
            <div>
               <a href="#" class="btn">View profile</a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>

{% endblock content %}
```

[image]

```css
<title>Profile</title><!DOCTYPE html> {
  % block styles %
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: arial;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 430px;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 1px #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.upper-container {
  height: 150px;
  background: #7F00FF;
}

.image-container {
  background: white;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  transform: translate(100px, 100px);
}

.image-container img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.lower-container {
  height: 280px;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.lower-container h3,
h4 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: .6;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.lower-container h4 {
  color: #7F00FF;
  opacity: .6;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.lower-container p {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: gray;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.lower-container .btn {
  padding: 12px 20px;
  background: #7F00FF;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
}

.lower-container .btn:hover {
  background: transparent;
  color: #7F00FF;
  border: 2px solid #7F00FF;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="upper-container">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="profile.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="lower-container">
      <div>
        <h3>Alaina Wick</h3>
        <h4>Front-end Developer</h4>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>sodales accumsan ligula. Aenean sed diam tristique, fermentum mi nec, ornare arch.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="#" class="btn">View profile</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you provide a snapshot of the page?

Comment: @Kouen Just did it

Comment: HTML5 has an actual <footer> tag you can use

Comment: I have that in my base.html

Comment: this is overriding that

Comment: i think you should add a br tag if i am right you should read about floating and the error about it. you could put a br tag before the offending div
example
<div class="main">
<div class="Content">
</div>
<br />
<div class="footer Culprit">
</div>
</div>
that is one way
other is to use Clearfix classes

Comment: @Rez Is this supposed to be a "pop-up" kind of thing that will always stay in the center of the page?

Comment: @Kouen You should use `clear: both` to clear a `float`. `<br />` should only be used when it has semantic meaning (e.g. within a paragraph).

Comment: @John No, just really a profile card

Comment: I think you need to add a z-index to the `.card-containe` class.  Such as `z-index: 99;`

Comment: @Kouen The br tags didn't work

Comment: @John That didn't quite work either. It made it so it overlaps it solidly instead of it being see through, but it's still overlapping. I think it has something to do with the body {} in styles maybe effecting everything?

Comment: OK. I studied a long back HTML/CSS i don't recall much.

Comment: and clearfix classes?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_clearfix.asp

Comment: it seems that it s inherited code from base.html You should check that and Override in some way

Comment: check in developer options in your browser and inspect the class (F12)
check for inconsistencies from your desired state and the present state

Comment: Make that snippet reproduce this issue right here.

Comment: have you tried display:block? instead of inline-block? (Cardcontainer) with inline-block it stacks up.

Comment: @Rez I posted an answer. Please take a look (I just updated it right now a little in case you saw it when I posted it)

Comment: @John what part did uupdate

Comment: I added the `position: absolute;` part to my answer where I said to remove it from the card-container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is happening because of this code:

```
 top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

And also `position: absolute;`

It will always be in the center of the page even when the footer is there.  What I did is made a new container div, then text-aligned the items to be in the center instead of doing that with `top` or `left`

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: arial;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 430px;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 1px #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;

}

.upper-container {
  height: 150px;
  background: #7F00FF;
}

.image-container {
  background: white;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  transform: translate(100px, 100px);
}

.image-container img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.lower-container {
  height: 280px;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.lower-container h3,
h4 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: .6;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.lower-container h4 {
  color: #7F00FF;
  opacity: .6;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.lower-container p {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: gray;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.lower-container .btn {
  padding: 12px 20px;
  background: #7F00FF;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
}

.lower-container .btn:hover {
  background: transparent;
  color: #7F00FF;
  border: 2px solid #7F00FF;
}

.main-container{
  text-align: center;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<title>Profile</title>


<html>
   <head>
      <title>Profile Card</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
   </head>
   <body>
   <div>
   here is some text and stuff
   </div>
   <div class="main-container">
      <div class="card-container">
         <div class="upper-container">
            <div class="image-container">
               <img src="profile.jpg" />
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="lower-container">
            <div>
               <h3>Alaina Wick</h3>
               <h4>Front-end Developer</h4>
            </div>
            <div>
               <p>sodales accumsan ligula. Aenean sed diam tristique,
                  fermentum mi nec, ornare arch.
               </p>
            </div>
            <div>
               <a href="#" class="btn">View profile</a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
         </div>
   <div>
   A footer will probably be here sfg sg sg gsfg sg fsdg sgsdg sd
   </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you , that worked! Question, how do I make this bigger? On second thought, I'm not sure this is the best for what I'm trying to do. I honesty just need to display a profile with a photo and bio for a user to see on their own profile. Though I could use this card for my matching feature. Do u recommend anything for just a simpe profile display page ?

Comment: You want the card to be bigger?  Simply change the width and height in the `.card-container` class to something bigger